# Deployment to shared host without SSH (PHP)

Tags: php, deployment, ftp

I have a Web-Application running on Shared Hosting. I need to Update the Project and I don't have SSH. All the Best-Practice-Solutions so far for SHared Hosting included SSH.

So does anyone have experiences with deployment without SSH, not using manual uploading with FTP?

--dazz

edit: My dev environment is WinXP with XAMPP, I use SVN, hostet with XP-Dev.
As I understand it, if I want to use rsync, I have to have SSH. So no rsynch either.

Comment: @dazz what do you mean deploying with SSH, you still need to upload the files somehow why not with ftp? you mean deploy code from svn? or wget it from somewhere?

Comment: Just to make sure I understood your question : You can't use SSH and you don't want to use FTP, am I right ?

Comment: the grammar police just died looking at this

Comment: @c0mrade: At the moment, I export the svn-project, delete everything from the project-webspace, and upload everything from the export with FTP.
I don't have any build-script like ant for the deployment,it's not cool this way and it takes too long.

Comment: @jfoucher Yes, you are right. I can use FTP, but I don't want to check if I changed one file or not.

Comment: @dazz Most FTP clients should offer the option to skip copying unchanged files. I know filezilla does. That way you get much faster transfer times, if that's what you're worried about.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using rsync if you are using a Unix system or the Windows implementation [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)? Unison might also be a good cross-platform alternative.

Comment: I'm not reputable enough yet to include more than one link. Here is the link for Unison: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/
Both programs mentioned are GNU open-source.

Comment: For DeltaCopy and Synchrify I need to install a server, which i cannot on shared-hosting.
Unison sounds good. It seems it is not so nice with userinterface, but anyway, I will have a look into it.